# Powershell - Get total jobs printed from list of printers

Tags: powershell

Trying to get total jobs printed.
It works fine for one printer:

```
cls
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "10.240.16.156/server/JOBLOG.htm"
$Total = $WebResponse.AllElements | Select innerText | Select -Index '12'
$Total
```

Output:

```
innerText             
---------             
Total Jobs Printed:737
```

But I need to get that information from five hundred printers, that IP's I have in .csv file:

```
"PortName"
"10.240.8.27"
"10.240.9.87"
"10.240.19.81"
...
```

Tried to import IP from CSV, but it only uses last IP from .csv and cannot build a valid url:

```
cls
$Printers = Import-Csv -Path C:\path\to\csv\_printers.csv
$Url = "http://$PortName/server/JOBLOG.htm"
$WebResponse = ForEach ($PortName in $Printers) {Invoke-WebRequest $Url}
$Total = $WebResponse.AllElements | Select innerText | Select -Index '12'
ForEach ($PortName in $Printers) {
$Total
}
```

Output:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value "http://@{PortName=10.240.11.86}/server/JOBLOG.htm" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not 
be parsed."
At line:4 char:68
+ ... bResponse = ForEach ($PortName in $Printers) {Invoke-WebRequest $Url}
+                                                                     ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: do you want to preserve the `innerText` property or you want just the values in index 12?

Comment: Just index 12 value would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for something like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\path\to\csv\_printers.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Url = "http://{0}/server/JOBLOG.htm" -f $_.PortName

    [pscustomobject]@{
        URL      = $Url
        Response = (Invoke-WebRequest $Url).AllElements.InnerText[12]
    }
}
```

The error message is actually showing you the object being converted to a string (**`@{PortName=10.240.11.86}`**):

```
.. Cannot convert value "http://@{PortName=10.240.11.86}/server/JOBLOG.htm" ..
```

You need to expand the `PortName` property from your object to get the value (only the IP), hence the use of `$_.PortName` in my example.